# HTTPS blocked for Ionic build --release android apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Debug apk works fine, which rules out the usual suspects, but when I build, sign, install the release version, no https $http API calls can be made by angular (http to the same endpoint, which I permitted for debugging, works).

cordova whitelist is installed
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

manifest.xml contains the correct directives

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Ionic config.xml contains the correct directives

```
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

My index.html declares a permissive Content-Security-Policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I also checked my intermediate certificate chain using two different online SSL checkers--they are fine.

I'm totally stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re-apply SSL certs taking special care to include intermediary certs.

Despite https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/ and three other SSL checkers saying my SSL certs were fine, just to be safe I reset and configured my AWS Elastic Load Balancer SSL settings ensuring we I had included the (says optional, but not optional) intermediate cert, and the problem went away after that.

Comment: We're having similar issue (on some Androids but not the others, which is puzzling). I found [SSL checker](https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker) complaining about certificate chain (as the only SSL checker), and `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourhost.com:443` shows the chain is in fact there, but prints `Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)`.

Comment: @jakub.g I had this same problem and to fix it I had to email my CA's customer support and they gave me the proper root and intermediate certificates to use. COMODO had multiple root certs on their website and I was just using the wrong one.

Comment: In our case the problem turned out to be [a bug in Chromium](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164066/how-to-explain-ssl-cert-validation-discrepancy-between-chrome-and-webview-on-a-m) - finally we switched from Symantec cert to Comodo cert and it solved the issue

Comment: Thanks alot man! you saved my day. I was in trouble since 2 days. Thanks a lot to you....

Answer (score 1):

```
Modify this function in SystemWebViewClient.java found in
```

> platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
  final String packageName = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
  final PackageManager pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

  ApplicationInfo appInfo;
  try {
    appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
      // debug = true
      handler.proceed();
      return;
    } else {
      // debug = false
      // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO CHANGE:
      // 1. COMMENT THIS LINE
      // super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
      // 2. ADD THESE TWO LINES
      // ---->
      handler.proceed();
      return;
      // <----
    }
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // When it doubt, lock it out!
    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
  }
}
```

This will ignore if there is any SSL error occured on third party signed self generated certificates.
read in detail [here](http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/)

Comment: This isn't really a solution but more of a work around. As the link states you should not use this in a production app.

Comment: This will ignore if there is any SSL error occured on third party signed self generated certificates. I have stated the reason. If the SSL is not self signed then it wont pose any error.