# Ionic Android release apk cannot access https

Tags: android, ionic-framework

My https requests work fine in the debug apk, but as soon as I build and sign a release version the app can't make https requests to my API. Regular http requests work fine however.

I looked up the problem everywhere and the only solution I seem to be able to find is to ensure I have intermediate certs included on the server, which I do.

Comment: Related: [HTTPS blocked for Ionic build --release android apk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36817299/245966)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem when i am using Google Play Game services . The solution to my problem , is that i am using the sha1 certificate fingerprint for my debug apk and its working fine but when i sign the apk and release it it's wont work , So i get the sha1 certificate fingerprint for my release apk as well which is different from debug apk. so what i understand in your case is the certificate that you have passed for debug is different from release. So try to get the certificate for release version of the APK file.